# Can I use "when it comes to" like the following?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm comparing my old house and my current house. First, I'd like to talk about my old house and then I will talk about my current house. In this situation, I need to bring up the topic of my old house. To this end, can I use "when it comes to" like the following? If not, is there any suggestion?

> What I like about living in my old house is that there was a spacious yard. I remember that I played basketball with my younger brother ther. ***But when it comes to my current house***, there's no yard, which makes me miss my old house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using it quite right. It's a bit forced when comparing only two things.

**I  rush through the aisles of the supermarket, not wanting to waste much time there, and the canned music is often terrible, so I want to get out quickly. One box of oatmeal is as good as the next. But when it comes to avocados and melons, I'll take my time, looking for ripe ones.**

**In general, he's a real slob. But when it comes to his car, he's a neat-freak. He keeps it clean and shiny, and the interior is immaculate.**

**Most of the time you can just hop in the car and drive. But when it comes to taking a long road-trip, it's advisable to have the car checked out beforehand at the garage.**

**My uncle Joe tends to dislike professional athletes, thinking they're paid far more than any one person deserves for kicking or throwing a ball around. But when it comes to the Boston Bruins, they're gods who walk on water.**

Comment: Then here, what can I use instead of it. I think 'as for' is just the right thing. Am I right?

Comment: But with my new house....    You can toss boxes of breakfast cereal into your cart; *but with* melons, you should take your time and pick a ripe one.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "when it comes to" sounds a little wordy and unnatural to me as a native US English speaker. Another transitional phrase that might sound better:

> In my new house, on the other hand, there's no yard...

or switched:

> On the other hand, in my new house there's no yard...